# Git swallowing inline code excerpts in commit messages

Tags: git

I don't understand why Git is swallowing inline code in Git commit messages. For a commit message such as

```
Update `tests.py`
```

I am seeing the following

```
Update
```

in the Git log. Why is that? Is there a way to get it process the code markup?

Comment: It's executing `tests.py` and replacing it with the result, which is empty in this case, since it probably cannot find `tests.py`. This would not happen if you edited the commit message in an editor. You could try working around it by escaping the backquotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your comments in single quotes then it won't execute test.py. As in

```
git commit -m 'Update `test.py`'
```

Comment: In other words, it's not git who's to blame. It's bash that will read your `tests.py` part of the command and say ```ok, I have to replace this part of the command for what is coming out of tests.py```. It's just like running: ```git commit -m "Update $(( tests.py ))"```

Comment: I do that: I use ```git commit -m "Update `tests.py`"``` but what I see is in the Git log is that this becomes `"Update "`.

Comment: @srm well your still using double quotes not single quotes. Have you tried it with single quotes?

Comment: @srm This is about 5 years too late, but you need to escape the backticks: `git commit -m "Update \\`tests.py\\`"`.